# Changing text inside an iframe with JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML page which loads some content in an iframe with the help of remote JS. I want to replace the text "premium content" with something else.

What I am trying is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gaand.comli.com/no.js"></script>

<img src="psss" onerror="myFunction()"></img>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("overlay_iframe");
    var y = x.contentDocument;
    y.document.body.innerHTML = y.document.body.innerHTML.replace('premium', 

'newtext'); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to change it as soon as the page is loaded completely?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to have event when page loads, and then replace html content.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#overlay_iframe" ).html( $( "#overlay_iframe" ).html().replace("premium","newtext"));
});
```

Comment: Still not working. I can change text on a page easily. But in this case with iframe not working

Answer (score 0):

Unless the iFrame is on your server you cannot change it. I would suggest using PHP

```
file_get_contents()
```

and replacing it within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the jQuery .contents() to return an object of the iframes contents and than manipulate that. [jQuery .contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

```
$.getScript("http://gaand.comli.com/no.js")
.done(function(script) {
    s = setInterval(function() {
      $("iframe").contents()
      .find("body").text(function(_, o) {
         return o.replace("premium", "newText");
      }) && clearInterval(s);
    }, 10);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/whjqqtco/

Comment: it returns me a blank page without any frame

Comment: Tried without `$.getScript()` ? With `script` tag , as at OP ? Then `setInterval` piece in next `script` block ?

Comment: yes tried just now. Again I can see "Premium Content Area". Its no replaced by newText

Comment: If possible , can post `iframe` `html` ? Is piece inside of `img`'s `error` function ? , or in separate script tag / block ?

Comment: img tag I just used to call the myfunction(). actually what I am trying to do is. when I use <script src="http://gaand.comli.com/no.js"></script> in an html. This no.js loads an iframe and I need to change the text in it using js. I dont have source for the iframe as its loaded with this JS.

Comment: @user1111111111111 What is expected return value of `http://gaand.comli.com/no.js` ? Is piece expected to append an `iframe` element to document.body ? Tried at http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6sLerf44/ , got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null `

Comment: Got this error `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.widgetmonetize.info". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` Could possibly load the script - to fetch the source - retrieve source of the `iframe` , build the `iframe` contents - including changing html - then append/load the scripts attached to the iframe.